# HTTP authentication and SOAP request

Tags: java, android, soap, wsdl

Is there any solution to call SOAP services, which are secured with HTTP authentication?

I am working with this wsdl file: https://www.smoneybox.com/service/service.wsdl

I've tried to add headerOut to SoapSerializationEnvelope object, but without success. 
Can you please help me?

Michal

Answer (score 1):

Can you add HTTP header elements like username and password (Which is not secure).

I have done this by adding the username and API key as a part of the SOAP headers. I'm not sure how the web services are implemented in your case.

Comment: can you please post how did you add those credentials?? ty

Comment: I used SOAP UI which allows you to add SOAP and HTTP headers.